# Presenting unpublished work at PhD defense. What will happen if the committee are excessively critical of the results?

Tags: phd, thesis-committee, defense

I am about to defend my thesis and part of my presentation would involve results and conclusions from my two unpublished works. Personally, I am confident about the results and conclusions. My advisor is yet to work on the drafted manuscripts so she is familiar with the results but has not critically thought about the numerical methodology implemented or any other issues with the results. I have presented the results in different conferences, but again, no one really asks questions at conferences. These were not conference proceedings, so no peer review has been carried out yet.

So, I was wondering, what will happen if the committee (who are experts in my field) sees a potential fault with my work which I might have overseen? What if the potential fault undermines the works I have done? Will that lead to a negative outcome in my defense?

Comment: Take a deep breath. Calm down. Relax, even. Your defense will go just fine.

Comment: In some fields (such as mine) almost all work that will be presented as a thesis defense will be unpublished as PhDs have to be finished in a time scale that makes it very hard to publish your work before the defense. Don't worry, no work is perfect and your committee will understand this.

Comment: @IanSudbery, I think the OP means that it is based partly on the unpublished work of others. Not their own.

Comment: @Buffy oh no! It's my yet to be published works.  I am just concerned that I might have done things wrong in my work. Since they are yet to be peer reviewed, I am not sure if they are technically sound or they have some logical fallacies.

Comment: Oops. Missed it. Thanks for the clarification. I think my answer still works.

Comment: @IanSudbery: Agreed that unpublished content in a dissertation can be normal: While in my field (applied CS), publishing several papers every year during one's doctoral candidacy is the norm, I was explicitly told that even a "stapler thesis" should be constructed as previously published works plus something "extra", some new findings (or even just overarching conclusions) *on top* of what has already been published elsewhere. Thus, unpublished content in the thesis is not necessarily a flaw, it can even be a requirement.

Comment: Aren't you required to give copies of your thesis to your committee members well in advance? ... so that they could identify any serious problems?

Comment: @paulgarrett yes, but I don't know their comments or decisions yet

Comment: Couldn't you politely ask them if they have any comments, corrections, criticisms, etc?

Comment: @paulgarrett it's forbidden to contact the committee before defense. They will let me know their decision only during my defense. Now that I think about it, my post was a complete rant and impulsive in nature. What they would comment or decide is out of my control. I should just focus on giving my best that day. I believe, that's what everyone here's trying to tell me.

Comment: You system is very different than mine, in which there are many opportunities to repair any problems before the actual defense... in part because the rule is that to fail the thesis defense is permanent. No second chance.

Comment: @paulgarrett in my department, the defense is scheduled only after the external and internal committee members have given their comments and have green signaled the defense. But their comments are provided only on the day of defense.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with the comment of Jon Custer, you could, indeed, have an issue if someone, validly, finds a flaw. But, assuming everyone is rational (not always valid, I know), it is unlikely to result in total failure.

I've had students in such situations (not my own, but I was a committee member). We just sent the student back to work to resolve the issue and re-schedule a defense after the dissertation was revised as appropriate.

But, it is what it is. If objections are raised, do your best to explain why you accepted the papers. That is, show due diligence and that you seriously considered the arguments. But anyone can make a mistake, either you or the person raising an issue. Work it out.

I hope you have a rational committee. And good luck. If they are rational, then fining a flaw now is better for you than finding it later, I think.